# "Within", "in", "during", or "over" ? I will call him ---------- the next break

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Consider you are in a meeting. The meeting is going to continue for the next several hours. Therefore, some breaks have been devised in order to let people refresh themselves.

Now consider a brief conversation between two guys sitting near each others:

> A: Did you notify C that you would be here until 9:00 ?
>
> B: I will call him ........... the next break.

Which one of the prepositions listed below is the best choice?

- within
- during
- in
- over

---

**My interpretation:**

Using [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20the%20next%20break%2C%20during%20the%20next%20break%2C%20within%20the%20next%20break%2C%20over%20the%20next%20break&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20next%20break%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cduring%20the%20next%20break%3B%2Cc0), I can easily rule out "over" and "within" although I have no idea why they are wrong.

Now, the question is what is the difference between "in" and "during" in that context?

Comment: These guys are in a meeting but can never be in a break. That's a clue that is.

Comment: Idiomatically, *I'll do it **over / within** the next X* are normally only used in contexts where *X = a span of time* (eg: *I'll do it within the next hour*). If you say you'll do it ***over** the next hour*, you're implying you may spend most or all of that hour doing it, but ***within, in***, and to a lesser extent ***during*** don't necessarily imply that (perhaps when you finally *do* "do it", it'll only take a few seconds).

Comment: It's interesting how that Ngram changes when you change [_break_ to _hour_](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+next+hour%2Cduring+the+next+hour%2Cwithin+the+next+hour%2Cover+the+next+hour&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're talking about [either or both] a particular period of time and something that happens within the same time frame as another event, the *only* correct answer is "during". If you'd like to learn more about this, visit the intermediate English grammar lesson on Speakspeak for [prepositions of time](http://speakspeak.com/english-grammar-exercises/intermediate/prepositions-of-time-during-over-for-by-until) lesson.

Comment: "During" is the best answer.  Colloquially, any of those will work and be understood.