# In/During the lunch break

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

We got into a big fight. It happened in/during the lunch break, so everybody was there.

Question 1: In North America is "lunch break" the natural term for the break at work around noon where you eat?

Question 2: Is both "in" and "during" possible?

Comment: This is two questions, one of which is a duplicate of: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/101459/41273

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Within", "in", "during", or "over" ? I will call him ---------- the next break.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/101459/within-in-during-or-over-i-will-call-him-the-next-break) See also [“at lunch break” vs “in lunch break”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133922/) and [“Lunch”, “Break”, “Out to lunch”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/176031/lunch-break-out-to-lunch)